# Socket read and write simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

i am trying to write a very simple socket program, what i basically want is that the client keeps listening for communication from the server, in a while(true) loop. now i also want client to be able to send some data back to the server in the middle of it listening.

The only solution i can think of is making a thread for the read and write, and interrupting the read thread everytime i have to do a write.

is there a better solution or is this the only way i can do this

Comment: Please edit your post to provide more details about your work.  What have you tried?  What research have you done?  What code is not working?

Comment: It's just not an issue - see @CrazyCasta answer.  Tx/rx streams are independent and read from one thread while write from another is fine.

Comment: R/W simultaneously is the definition of Full-duplex, which TCP is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two threads. One for reading and one for writing. This way the write thread can write whenever it pleases (don't need to stop the read).

Another way to do it is to use `setSoTimeout(timeoutMs)` on the socket before calling read. This will cause it to throw a `SocketTimeoutException` if it takes longer than timeoutMs milliseconds to read, allowing you to then write as you please.

Comment: I would agree to this apart from the timeout part. Why would you want that? You can write anyway.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau Allows you to use one thread instead of two. I'm not exactly sure what the OP is trying to do so I was just adding another option.

Comment: There are some serious sync issues that can arise from that. And if you timeout, the socket is closed, or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but http://www.coderanch.com/t/554859/java/java/clarification-needed-setSoTimeout seems to suggest it will not close the socket. And other than possibly closing the socket what sync issues would arise?

Comment: Ok, I will look that up, thanks :) Well, the server may start sending something and then get interrupted, and the client has to wait until it can send. I just don't see the upside of that solution.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau The server will not get interrupted. It can still send so long as there is buffer space on the client (which I would assume would be for quite a while). And TCP is full-duplex, so there is no "wait until it can send" unless it's already filled up the "pipe" with as much bandwidth as the connection can provide to the server.

Comment: Ok, so if you are interrupted while receiving data, the data is redelivered to the app? Nice, if true. But yes, you are waiting for the timeout until you send if there is an ongoing read.

Comment: Yes to your second point. I was hypothesizing that perhaps the OP wanted to send some data at periodic intervals. Since we don't know what the OP really wants, it's hard to come up with an answer.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau No, the socket is not closed if you get a read timeout.

Comment: It's obvious that I need to play with socket timeout today :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the FTP protocol specs. It does what you intend to do using two socket/channels, one for commands and one for data.

Comment: That is not needed. One socket is enough for sending and receiving on two separate channels.

Answer (score -1):

You can use two different ports, one for listening and one for writing. and use different threads to do the operations, then you while(true) loop wont create a problem.

Comment: That is what a socket does... It already supports full duplex.